# Build failing with exception

Tags: reactjs, react-native

when I run (React-native run-android)  Its gives an error below:

info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
27 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 25 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:installDebug'.

  > File 'C:\Users\skpul\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe' specified for property 'adbExe' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:installDebug'.

  > File 'C:\Users\skpul\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe' specified for property 'adbExe' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\skpul\MyRe\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\skpul\MyRe\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:169:41)
at then.result (C:\Users\skpul\MyRe\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:135:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Try creating a clean project with `create-react-native-app` and testing whether the same issue is present there

Answer (score 1):

the problem related the emulator,
restart your emulator or device, the problem will solved